# Python list dir to only list directories

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I need to list a dir and detect folders and files inside,

For that I wanted to make 2 vars, one called `content_folders` which will return the folder and one other for the files, but I'm having issue to make `content_folders`.

```
def folder_check(root_path):
     for item in root_path:
          if os.path.isdir(item):
               return item
```

this is how I'm trying to list `content_folders` then use it :

```
elif content == "brandings":
    title="Brandings"
    root_path = os.listdir(os.path.join(
                                    app.static_folder,
                                    f'content/{content}/'))
    content_folders = folder_check(root_path)
    return render_template('base.html', 
                                    content=content, 
                                    title=title, 
                                    content_folders=content_folders
                                    )
```

and it returns none in my jinja template so I can't make a for loop.

Comment: you're assuming you hit your `if` condition in the first snippet you shared. if not, you'll return none. your code does not seem to anticipate that case.

Comment: yeah it returns none and I don't really know how I can make it work

Comment: `os.listdir` returns only names, but you need the full path in the condition. Even then, `folder_check` would only return the first folder found, not all folders.

Comment: I think I'll simply use 2 folders to split images and folders, it will be way simpler.

Answer (score 0):

[os.walk](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) is probably what you want.

> Generate the file names in a directory tree by walking the tree either
> top-down or bottom-up. For each directory in the tree rooted at
> directory top (including top itself), it yields a 3-tuple (dirpath,
> dirnames, filenames).

Example:

```
import os
from os.path import join, getsize
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('python/Lib/email'):
    print(root, "consumes", end=" ")
    print(sum(getsize(join(root, name)) for name in files), end=" ")
    print("bytes in", len(files), "non-directory files")
    if 'CVS' in dirs:
        dirs.remove('CVS')  # don't visit CVS directories
```

Comment: No, they are not trying to do a recursive walk. (I suppose that you could put an unconditional `break` so that it exits after the first iteration, which should then just output the contents of the top-level directory, but I think the code would still be potentially confusing. It would at least need some clarifying comment in the code to assist the reader.)